# How to add custom attribute to a tracelistener in Config file in wpf application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, configuration-files, tracelistener

I have the following log file tracelistener which extends the filelogtracelistener and it works fine and I am able to log the messages, but I want to specify an additional custom attribute in this e.g. MaxUsers and below is how it should look.

```xml
 <add name="myFileListener" 
      type="MyCustomFileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.MyTools.Connections" 
      BaseFileName="IncidentTracking"
      Location="LocalUserDirectory" MaxUsers="500" />
```

Currently this attribute is custom so the config file gives errors. How can I add a custom attribute like that and consume it back in my code ?

What I think as a solution is we can add a custom configuration section but want to know if Out of the box we can try something and better solution?

Comment: It is possible to add custom attributes to your trace listeners. Check my answer for an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

According to this article, the [TraceListener.Attributes Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.attributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) gets the custom trace listener attributes defined in the application configuration file.

it also quotes:

> Classes that are derived from the **TraceListener** class can add custom
>   attributes by overriding the **GetSupportedAttributes** method and
>   returning a string array of custom attribute names.

I was able to implement what you wanted by following [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.getsupportedattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this

```
string[] _supportedAttributes = new string[] { "MaxUsers", "maxusers", "maxUsers" };

/// <summary>
/// Allowed attributes for this trace listener.
/// </summary>
protected override string[] GetSupportedAttributes() {
    return _supportedAttributes;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the value of Max Users Attribute 
/// </summary>
public int MaxUsers {
    get {
        var maxUsers = -1; // You can set a default if you want
        var key = Attributes.Keys.Cast<string>().
            FirstOrDefault(s => string.Equals(s, "maxusers", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key)) {
            int.TryParse(Attributes[key], out maxUsers);
        }
        return maxUsers;
    }
}
```

This would then allow me to add custom attribute to config file which would look like

```
<add name="myFileListener" type="MyCustomFileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.MyTools.Connections" 
      BaseFileName="IncidentTracking"
      Location="LocalUserDirectory" MaxUsers="500" />
```

**Note :**

The Attributes collection is not populated from the configuration file until **after** the instance of your listener is fully constructed. You need to make sure it is called after your listener object is completely instantiated, but before it is first used.

Answer (score -1):

No it is not possible to change the schema, so you have to add a custom section.
There are a lot of articles out there explaining how it is done like this one [create a custom config section](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20548/Creating-a-Custom-Configuration-Section-in-C)